How to make selection and click in same blocks based on text context
There is such a structure, a week:
<li class="list-group-item">
<strong>Wednesday</strong>
<br>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="10"/>
09:45 AM - 11:00 AM </label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="20"/>
11:30 AM - 02:00 PM </label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="30"/>
05:00 PM - 08:00 PM</label>

</li>

<li class="list-group-item">
<strong>Thursday</strong>
<br>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="40"/>
09:45 AM - 11:00 AM </label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="50"/>
11:30 AM - 02:00 PM </label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="dtf" value="60"/>
05:00 PM - 08:00 PM</label>

</li>

Depending on the desired day of the week, I need to click, for example, in the place where there is text 11:30 AM - 02:00 PM.
I can do the following and click on block with text of day of week:
var recital = await page.$$('.list-group-item');

for (let i = 0; i < recital.length; i++) {
var text = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, recital[i]);
if(text.indexOf("Thursday") > -1 )
    {
    try {
        await recital[i].click();
            console.log("Click!");
    } catch {
            console.log("No click!");
    }}}

How click on text 11:30 AM - 02:00 PM under Thursday in block try?
Solved (cycle within a cycle):
var recital = await page.$$('.list-group-item');
console.log("length:", recital.length);

for (let i = 0; i < recital.length; i++) {

    var text = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, recital[i]);
        if(text.indexOf("Thursday") > -1 )
        {

            var sd = await recital[i].$$('label');
            console.log("length of time:", sd.length);
                
                for (let j = 0; j < sd.length; j++) {
                    
                    var sday = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, sd[j]);
                    console.log("what time is it:", sday);
                        
                        if(sday.indexOf("11:30 AM - 02:00 PM") > -1 )
                        {
                            try {
                                await sd[j].click();
                                console.log("Click!");
                            } catch {
                                console.log("No click!");
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
}


You're in the ballpark. This isn't particularly easy to do with plain locators, so I'd use browser code, in this case, I'd select by the Thursday text, then use .closest("li") to pop up to the parent container and then querySelector into the subtree to find the label by text.
The following approach issues an untrusted click, so if you want a trusted click, change $$eval to evaluateHandle and return the label.
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.10.0

const html = `<Your HTML>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = "li strong::-p-text(Thursday)";
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  const labelText = await page.$eval(sel, el => {
    const label = [...el.closest("li").querySelectorAll("label")]
      .find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "11:30 AM - 02:00 PM");
    label.click();
    return label.textContent.trim();
  });
  console.log(labelText); // => 11:30 AM - 02:00 PM
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

